# how to proof that $1,9999.... \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: integers

I want to prove that $1,999\dots$ Is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$. Here is my try :

$x = 1,9999\dots \\ 
10x = 19,9999\dots \\
10x - x = 18  \\
9x = 18  \\
x = 18/9  \\
x = 2 $

So $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

I know something is wrong but where ?

Comment: How do you *define* $1.999 \ldots$ ?

Comment: 1 with a infinity of 9999 after the comma

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong with what you wrote?

Comment: @Mathematician42 because $1,9\dots \neq 2$...

Comment: Actually you have just proved that they are indeed equal. Well done. And no, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: That's where you are wrong. They are equal! Many people just don't realize that the decimal representation of real numbers is not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x=1+9\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}10^{-i} $$

$$=1+9\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}(\frac {1}{10})^i$$

$$=1+9\frac {1}{10}\frac {1}{1-\frac {1}{10}}$$

$$=1+9\frac{1}{10}\frac {10}{9}=2$$